# "Forecast" library can't be installed

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R and as I'm following a script from another one, I'm in trouble for the fact I can't install (and recall) the "forecast" library.
I've already read other posts but it seems no solutions have been successfully so far.

Some info:

1. I installed R from "Cran -R-project"
2. I simply tried to install the packages "forecast" from usual
   server (Italy) and after my installation I finally got this message:

   > package ‘forecast’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   >
   > The downloaded binary packages are in
   >           C:\Users\"myname"\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYjiY2w\downloaded_packages
3. However, when I insert: `library(forecast)` it returns me this:

   ```
   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
     there is no package called ‘scales’
   Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
   ```
4. My version is the 3.3.2    I don't know what to do, really I'm a
   dumb with this software, it's just three days I'm using.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Your answer is in step 3.  `install.packages("scales")`

Comment: would you please choose the correct answer?

Comment: I had the same issue, It was solved by using @Amirkhm 's solution.

Answer (score 6):

Normally the problem is because of the curl.
Try to install or update your current version of Curl.
In linux Ubuntu use this:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using `install.packages("package_name")` to install additional R packages. `install.packages()` takes care of dependencies to other packages (like `scales` in your case) and avoids such problems.

```
install.packages("forecast")

library(forecast)
```

Comment: Ok thanks I realized what did you mean. I had to install "scales" and other two files (so overall the 3 steps you were talking about) and finally it worked! Thanks again

Comment: Not quite. If you run `install.packages("forecast")`, R will install not only the `forecast` package, but also all packages `forecast` depends on (like `scales`). Doing this, you don't need 3 steps, but only one.

Answer (score 1):

**Running @ottlngr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940960/1224827)...**

```
install.packages("forecast", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(forecast)
```

**...I got an error like this:**

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘TTR’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/TTR’
ERROR: dependencies ‘TTR’, ‘curl’ are not available for package ‘quantmod’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/quantmod’
ERROR: dependency ‘quantmod’ is not available for package ‘tseries’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tseries’
ERROR: dependency ‘tseries’ is not available for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/forecast’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp5kDaem/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘TTR’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘quantmod’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘tseries’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Running @Amirkhm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127494/1224827)...**

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

**...seemed to work, was able to install `forecast` and import the library without errors.**

Answer (score 1):

To install package on Ubuntu follow this steps:
update openssl (curl update) and libxml (Development files for the GNOME XML library),

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

then install packages with its dependencies:

```
install.packages('forecast', dependencies = TRUE)
```

this worked for me on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You can try this - Install MASS package first and then install 'forecast' with dependencies as TRUE. And install from sources which do not need compilation.

install.packages("MASS")

install.packages('forecast', dependencies = TRUE)

library(forecast)

> Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) no

This worked for me.